# Owner of Google Analytic account left company, how to retrieve?

Tags: google-analytics

The person responsible for a Google Analytics property has left our company and we have no way to contact them.

We know the UA code for the property identifier, but we don't know the email used to login to google.

Is there any way anyone is familiar with to get access to a GA property in this scenario?

Comment: This posting is not related to coding and should be asked in Webmasters.

Comment: If you have an adwords account connected to your Analytics property you might try to contact Adwords support. In my experience Google support is much more approachable when there is danger to loose money.

Comment: Since stack overflow is a coding site I will take this opportunity to remind folks that Google Analytics has a [User Permissions API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtUserPermissions) which if used properly the mistakes of having a company property with a single employee owner can be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contact a local [Google Analytics Certified Partner](https://www.google.com/analytics/partners/search/services) and if they are nice will put in a ticket for you to claim the GA account back.  You'll need to upload a text file to the website with some text showing it is yours.